# Remotely preventDefault() a Form in another Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, preventdefault

I'm not really sure how to ask/word this question but...

How can I prevent a form from submitting from another jQuery function? Basically, I have input fields with auto-complete functionality where the end-user can navigate through the results by using the up-and-down arrow keys. The end-user can press the Enter key to make a selection however that makes the form submit. I would like to prevent that from happening.

```
$('body').on('click keyup', '.inputField1', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode===13){           
        // Attempting to remotely prevent the form from submitting
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        form.preventDefault();
        form.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }

    // auto-complete logic below
    // ...

});
```

Please note that I've tried adding the logic above under `$('#myForm1').submit(function(e){ ...` but the enter key was not detected upon input.

Comment: If you mean that you've put the `on('click keyup`)` logic *inside* the `submit` function handler, then that's your problem. It should be placed in the scope of the document.ready handler function

Comment: What plugin are you using for autocomplete? pressing enter in that scenario should not be triggering an enter key event on the input.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No. I never implied that.

Comment: `Please note that I've tried adding the logic above under $('#myForm1').submit(function` In which case, what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: When you press the arrow key, focus should move from the input to the selection. At that point, pressing enter wouldn't submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to prevent the form submitting when the user hits "enter" while an input field is in focus:

You want to attach this handler to the input field itself, and should use the `keydown` or `keypress` event rather than `keyup` (which happens after the form submission has started).    What you're preventing isn't the form submit, but the default action of the event which *triggers* the form submit, so call `preventDefault()` on the event, not on the form.

`event.keyCode` and `event.which` are deprecated, but still universally supported.  The currently "correct"  way to do this would be `if (event.key === "Enter")` but this may not work in some older browsers (and note that current IE and Edge still use [nonstandard identifiers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key) for some keys.)

```js
// It's not necessary to delegate the event from 'body', unless the form field is added to the DOM after this is called.
$('.inputField1').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {  
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://example.com">
  <input class="inputField1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `keyup` on the input triggers before `submit` on the form.

If you change your event to `keypress` you'll find you can intercept the submit event before form submission.

Also, you should be using `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode` - jQuery standarizes `.which` but I don't think it does the same for `.keyCode`.

The following code sample will show this in action. The first text field will intercept when you press enter, the second will not.

```js
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('body').on('keypress', '.a', function(event) {
            if(event.which == 13) {
                alert('You pressed enter');
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="https://www.stackoverflow.com" onsubmit="alert('submit event');return false;">
    <input class="a" type="text">
    <input class="b" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```